# Laravel Github Actions CI/CD , SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: create table `migrations`

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to run my unit tests through my yml file, but they fail because they must be run on Mysql

I think something is missing.

here is yaml file:

```
steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '7.4|8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate

    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

    - name: Optimize Project
      run: php artisan optimize:clear

    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: mysql
        DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
        DB_PORT: 3306
        DB_DATABASE: database_name
        DB_USERNAME: root
        DB_PASSWORD:
      run: |
        php artisan migrate
        php artisan test
```

and here is phpunit.xml file:

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```

Comment: check your mysql status, database created? , user password and privileges

Comment: could you provide me the steps?

Comment: Where is your mysql server I mean on your machine or on docker container?

Answer (score 1):

[This example shows](https://dev.to/robertobutti/test-automation-for-laravel-7-and-mysql-with-github-actions-ijj) an example of adding MySQL into into your GitHub action, so the database is available:

Your GitHub actions yaml needs a `services` section:

```yaml
    services:
      # mysql-service Label used to access the service container
      mysql:
        # Docker Hub image (also with version)
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          ## Accessing to Github secrets, where you can store your configuration
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
        ## map the "external" 3306 port with the "internal" 3306
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        # Set health checks to wait until mysql database has started (it takes some seconds to start)
        options: >-
          --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping"
          --health-interval=10s
          --health-timeout=5s
          --health-retries=3
```

The `env` you can set with your GH Actions command that needs database access can include:

```yaml
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: mysql
        DB_DATABASE: test_db
        DB_USER: root
        DB_PASSWORD: root
```

You may want to check out Chipper CI, which does a lot of this work for you for testing Laravel apps!